# AS3 Referencing an object or variable via string etc

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I have found answers 'similar' to the one I'm looking for. I really hope I didn't overlook an already answered problem.

code:

```
var Randy:Object = {age:32, gender:1};
var Joey:Object = {age:35, gender:1};



var slot_0 = Randy;
var slot_1 = Joey;

myFunction();

function myFunction():void{
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
var thisObject = ("Slot_" + i);

trace(thisObject);     // example 1
trace(thisObject.age); //example 2
}
}
```

**it will trace in //example 1**

```
slot_0
slot_1
```

*if I 'trace(thisObject)' the 'name of the Objects' ("slot_0" ; "slot_1") trace out.*

**but in //example 2 I get:**

```
Error #1069: Property age not found on String and there is no default value.
```

*How do I get it to understand that I want it to reference the properties of the object itself? e.g. 'trace(**thisObject.age**) means **slot_0.age** witch means **Randy.age**  etc...*

Without a for-loop, I have to write a lot of redundant script, so I need to know this!

```
Thank You in advance for the help!
```

Comment: I don't know man, looks like you are trying to write JS in AS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var thisObject = this["slot_"+i];
```

That's how you can do a string reference. Of course, if the var is located elsewhere, use the proper parent object.

Comment: Could you elaborate? The code you gave throws an error. Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. And when I remove the keyword 'this', then I get no error, but it says the term is unidentified in the trace. --- Also, I'm using AS3 and there is no other code, other than what is above. It is all on the timeline, frame 1, with nothing else.

Comment: --- NEVERMIND ----  This worked! You capitalized the 's' in "slot_" + i, which threw an error, but after I noticed that, it did work! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo. Also, if this worked for you, please accept the answer by pressing a "tick" beside it.

Comment: Thanks again. Seems the keyword 'this' threw me in my logic. It seemed unnecessary. Good to know. Thanks.